# mod_python with Python 2.6 on Windows

Tags: python, apache, mod-python

How do I install mod_python to run with Python 2.6 on a Windows machine? I could not find an installer for Python 2.6.

I downloaded this installer for (mod_python on Python 2.5): [mod_python-3.3.1.win32-py2.5-Apache2.2.exe](http://apache.opensourceresources.org/httpd/modpython/win/3.3.1/mod_python-3.3.1.win32-py2.5-Apache2.2.exe) and extracted it to get PLATLIB and SCRIPTS folders. Where do I go from here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't. That's the install for Python 2.5 and [will not work.](http://www.modpython.org/pipermail/mod_python/2009-January/025957.html) You can try the [instructions here](http://badwords.org/w/Compile_mod_python_for_Python_2.6) or use mod_wsgi instead as they suggest.

Answer (score 2):

Nowhere. That is for Python 2.5. You'll need to build from [source](http://apache.mirror.rafal.ca:8080/httpd/modpython/mod_python-3.3.1.tgz) if you want it to work with 2.6, or wait for them to get around to it.